# TextView with gravity=center and ellipsize=marquee?

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, textview

I have a `TextView` with possibly very long text. Also the text should be centered when it is short enough to not cause the marquee effect.

This is the layout xml:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:focusable="false" android:lines="1"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" 
    android:ellipsize="marquee" 
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"></TextView>
```

also, I use `findViewById(R.id.TextView01).setSelected(true)` to immediately start the marquee.

When the text becomes too long and the marquee effect would kick in it just disappears. Short text is displayed and works.

When I remove the `android:gravity="center"` the text is visible and marquee works. But short text will no longer be centered in the `TextView`. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I'm using Android 2.2.

Edit2: When I replace android:lines="1" with the (deprecated) android:singleLine="true" everything works as expected, but this does not seem to be an ideal solution.

Comment: Anyone found a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the attribute android:line="1" to android:singleLine="True". It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `android:lines="1"` attribute to `android:inputType="text"`. Seems like a bug though.

Comment: I tried that but that does not seem to work. I can see long text but it won't scroll.